How can I dynamically adjust the kernel size in a CNN based on input image size using PyTorch?
I’m building a convolutional neural network (CNN) using PyTorch, and I want to make it a bit smarter when it comes to handling images of different sizes. Specifically, I’d like the kernel size of my convolutional layers to adjust based on the input image dimensions. For smaller images, I’d go with something like a (3, 3) kernel, but for larger images, I’d want to use a bigger kernel like (7, 7) or even (9, 9).
Here’s what I’ve come up with so far:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class DynamicCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_shape):
        super(DynamicCNN, self).__init__()
        
        # Extract input dimensions
        input_height, input_width = input_shape
        
        # Dynamically calculate kernel size based on input dimensions
        kernel_size = (input_height // 10, input_width // 10)
        
        # Define the CNN layers
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=32, kernel_size=kernel_size)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=32, out_channels=64, kernel_size=(3, 3))
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(64 * (input_height // 4) * (input_width // 4), 128)  # Adjust based on pooling
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(128, 10)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(torch.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(torch.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, self.num_flat_features(x))  # Flatten
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

    def num_flat_features(self, x):
        size = x.size()[1:]  # All dimensions except batch size
        num_features = 1
        for s in size:
            num_features *= s
        return num_features

# Example: Create the model with an input size of 64x64
input_shape = (64, 64)
model = DynamicCNN(input_shape)
print(model)


This code adjusts the kernel size based on the input image dimensions when the model is initialized. I think this should help make the network more adaptable, but I'm still unsure if this is the best approach. I’d love some feedback on a couple of things:

Is this the right way to dynamically calculate the kernel size in PyTorch, or is there a better (or more PyTorch-friendly) way to do this?
Will this approach scale well for larger images, or should I handle things differently?
Any tips or improvements would be greatly appreciated!


Your code doesn't "adjust kernel size based on the input image dimensions", it creates a brand new model for every image size. This approach doesn't really make sense because it requires you to train a new model for every image size.

Beyond that, larger kernel sizes don't give the performance boost you want. Older CNNs (2012-2015 era) used large kernel sizes in the early layers, but research has shown multiple layers with small kernels outperform larger kernels while being more parameter efficient (ie five 3x3 CNN layers have less parameters than a single 7x7 layer). Small kernels over multiple layers still perform well due to the increasing receptive field of the model.

what do you mean "adjust the kernel size"? how does the kernel vary depending on image size? is it a totally different kernel for different sizes, or is the 3×3 kernel somehow computed from the 7×7?
